# best practice for paintComponent()

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, graphics2d, jcomponent

I am rendering a rectangle using `Graphics` library of java, in it `paintComponent()` method draws the rectangle and everything is fine in drawing regards.

My question is does the `paintComponent` keeps on rendering or it just renders once and if a window change or any event occurs it changes the view. So I have written a simple `System.out.println` to check whether it keeps on printing it, and it does. So is there a way to stop that from happening or is it fine to leave rendering as it is, since it is completing my objective?

Comment: I'd say that because you _don't_ have full control over this, a good practice would be not to create/change/manipulate and state (that is used to paint), inside of the `paintComponent` method. Instead use class members as paint state, and change the state, say inside a listener callback, then repaint. The state will always remain the same with _implicit_ repaints, but will change upon _explicit_ repaint calls.

Answer (score 2):

Start by taking a look at [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/)

Swing uses a passive rendering engine, that is, it only paints when it feels that it has to.  Painting can happen for any number of reasons, many of which you don't control, but you can make a request to the repaint manager via the `repaint` method.

> So I have written a simple System.out.println to check whether it keeps on printing it, and it does

Would suggest that something is wrong, `paintComponent` shouldn't, under normal circumstances, be repeatedly called.  This can, of course, happen if you are doing animation and need to update the graphics.

> So is there a way to stop that from happening or is it fine to leave rendering as it is

Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This will result in less confusion and better responses.

Without some idea of what you are doing, there's no way to know what to suggest...

Comment: thanks for the response, I think I found the problem, now I can go and fix it.